# Android custom Adapter add data from asynctask will not be added

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

i currently try to add data received form an async task to an custom adapter. On first call of task there is an empty list of "notifications". on second and third call the received notifications had to add to existing list of notifications.

my Problem is new notifications wouldn't added to the existing list. new notifications going to replace the old list.

```
private class LoadNotificationsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<Notification>> {
    NotificationFragment fragment;
    String parameters;

    private LoadNotificationsTask(NotificationFragment fragment, String parameters) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Notification> doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            return Client.getNotifications(this.parameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ArrayList<Notification>();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Notification> notifications) {
        NotificationListAdapter notificationListAdapter = new NotificationListAdapter(notifications);
        setListAdapter(notificationListAdapter);
    }
}


public class NotificationListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Notification> notifications;

    public NotificationListAdapter(ArrayList<Notification> notifications) {
        super();
        this.notifications = notifications;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.notifications.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.notifications.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notificationlist_item, parent, false);
        }
        final Notification notification = (Notification) this.getItem(position);

        TextView headline = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notilist_hostname);
        headline.setText(notification.getNAME1() + "\\" +notification.getNAME2());


        return convertView;

    }
```

Comment: And what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: whats the problem. explain

Comment: calling the task first time works, calling the task a second or third time i the old notifications will be replaced by new one instead of adding it

Comment: try to not create your adapter in `onPostExecute` instead add notifications to adapter via a filter existing or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First initiate the ListView Adapter outside AsyncTask ie. inside onCreate()

```
 // Declare class variable
 ArrayList<Notification> mNotifications;
 NotificationListAdapter notificationListAdapter;

 // inside onCreate()
 mNotifications = new ArrayList<Notification>();
 notificationListAdapter = new NotificationListAdapter(mNotifications);
 setListAdapter(notificationListAdapter);
```

then edit your AsyncTask postExecute() with following code

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Notification> notifications) {
    mNotifications.addAll(notifications);
    notificationListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: argh so simple.... i tried to add the new notifications to adapter instead off the list. works great ! thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change getItemId function return value.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;//change return position;
}
```